# Randomly placing an element in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, random

For a game I have an ascii map, it is stored in an array. # represents a wall and . represents walkable space. At the start of the game the player needs to be randomly placed on a square that isn't a #, what is the most efficient algorithm for doing this? I could just randomly place the player and then do it again if the space isn't legal but I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Is your program's efficiency a problem right now?

Comment: It's not a problem, but I'd like it to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: And why wouldn't your solution be efficient?

Comment: Because it could potentially randomly select an illegal space many times in a row and waste several frames.

Comment: Do you randomly generate the game "map" or is it predefined somewhere?

Comment: It is predefined, but the user can add their own maps.

Comment: When you load in the map you should create an array of integers that represent the possible indices that a player may be placed at.

Answer (score 1):

"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Knuth

But, it depends on the ratio of walls to spaces:

If there are loads of spaces compared to walls, it probably will only have to re-try a small number of times before it finds one.

```
Random rnd = new Random();  
int space = -1;
while (space == -1) {
  int index = rnd.nextInt(positions.length);
  if (!isAWall(positions[index])) {
    space = positions[index];
  }
}
```

If there is only 1 space out of 1000s of walls, it may take a while to find randomly. In this case, it may be more sensible to get all of the spaces first, and choose randomly out of those known valid choices.

```
spaces = onlySpaces(positions);
Random rnd = new Random();  
space = spaces[rnd.nextInt(spaces.length)];
```

Comment: Well, the way it's set up at the moment allows users to create their own maps, so potentially they could make a map with a very high wall to space ratio, I guess it probably isn't worth optimizing around that though.

Answer (score 0):

I would run over the array once, and store all the indices of free spaces in a separate array, then randomly pick one of those indices.

That guarantees you linear complexity, whereas a completely random algorithm can have a very high worst case complexity or even run forever, if there are no free spaces.